# how to use specific rowmapper in abstractDAO

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, abstract-class, spring-jdbc

```
public abstract class AbstractDAO<T> implements IFindDAO {


    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;


    @Override
    public List<Trade> findOne(final int eventId) {
        return jdbcTemplate.query(getOneQuery(), new Object[]{eventId}, new TypeAMapper());
    }

    @Override
    public List<Event> getAll() {
        return jdbcTemplate.queryForList(getAllQuery(), Event.class);
    }


    protected abstract String getOneQuery();

    protected abstract String getAllQuery();

}
```

I have an Abstract DAO class like the one above. I have several DAO implementation that deal with different types I support that each return their own version of the `getOneQuery()` and `getAllQuery()`.

I have RowMappers as follows:

```
public class TradeMapper {

    public void map(Trade trade, ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
        //common trade type setting
    }

}
```

TypeA Mapper

```
public class TypeAMapper extends TradeMapper implements RowMapper<Trade> {

    @Override
    public Trade mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {

        Trade trade = new Trade();

        map(trade, rs, rowNum);

        return trade;
    }

}
```

TypeB Mapper

```
public class TypeBMapper extends TradeMapper implements RowMapper<Trade> {

    public TypeB mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {

        Trade trade = new TypeB();

        super.map(trade, rs, rowNum);

        TypeB typeB = (TypeB) trade;

        typeB.setSomethingABC(rs.getBigDecimal("ABC"));
        typeB.setSomethingABCDEF(rs.getString("ABCDEF"));

        return typeB;
    }

}
```

The `TypeBDAO` class has to use the `TypeBMapper` but in my `AbstractDAO` class I set it to `TypeAMapper`. What is the best way to ensure that my `TypeBDAO` uses `TypeBMapper` that has specific settings.

Can I improve this structure? I am using java 8

My `TypeB` model extends `Trade`

Answer (score 1):

In your `AbstractDAO` class add additional abstract method like `getRowMapper()`
and just provide different implementations in derived classes:

```
@Override
public List<Trade> findOne(final int eventId) {
    return jdbcTemplate.query(getOneQuery(), new Object[]{eventId}, getRowMapper());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a constructor to autowire the appropriate type.

Since `TypeBDAO` needs to use a `TypeBMapper`, `TypeBDAO` only accepts that particular type in its constructor:

```
public class TypeBDAO extends AbstractDAO {
   @Autowired
   public void (TypeBMapper mapper) {
       super(mapper);
   }
}
```

But the constructor just delegates to the super, which accepts the interface.  The methods can then use the mapper instead of attempting to creating a new instance.

```
public abstract class AbstractDAO<T> implements IFindDAO {
    private final RowMapper<T> mapper;

    public AbstractDAO(RowMapper<T> mapper) {
        this.mapper = mapper;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Trade> findOne(final int eventId) {
        return jdbcTemplate.query(getOneQuery(), new Object[]{eventId}, mapper);
  }
}
```

This assumes there are appropriate Spring managed beans available, and the mapper is thread safe.